# Import user defined component with React CDN,

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react with their CDN scripts (as well as react-dom and babel-standalone) that I've saved out to some files due to security practices with network connectivity, and am trying to figure out code organization.

Disclaimer: I'm aware that I need webpack or something to compile to get access to `require` or normal imports. I'm wondering if there's a way to organize my components without having to add a script tag in my main html for every single file.

**The error that I'm getting** is `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. The research that I've done is saying that I need to add each file used by my other javascript with a tag in the html. This is cumbersome especially if I have a large(ish) project. It's not scalable. How can I organize the various components that I have without having to have a massive `head` section with all of the wonderful script tags?

I've seen some hacks, but they're older and with the advent of new react versions and browser capabilities, so I thought I'd try and see what is being used out there to solve this problem now.

p.s. this is the first experience I have with React CDN, but I've written apps in RN before.

My code is:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="react.js" />
        <script src="react-dom.js" />
        <script src="babel.js" />
        <script type="text/jsx" src="app.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root" />
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
import Greeting from './greeting';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Greeting text='Hello World' />
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

greeting.js

```js
const Greeting = ({ text }) => {
    return (
        <h1>{text}</h1>
    );
}

export default Greeting;
```

Comment: First off you're not using a CDN if you've downloaded the scripts locally, that's instead called vendoring. Secondly, `require()` is something that exists in CJS and requires a bundler in order to make it usable. You cannot use `require()` in the browser.

Comment: 1. Fair enough, will edit the question to clarify. 2. That's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Importing greatings.js in app.js won't work. Instead, you import all the javascript files that you are using in the HTML file only then it would work.

```
<script type="text/babel" src="greatings.js"></script>
```

in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use React or JSX in the browser without some sort of build step. React only distributes CJS, no ESM, so it needs build tooling. Babel is used to transpile, though I'm not entirely sure it makes sense to use in this context. It's a lot of overhead.

Take a look at https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2020/react-without-build-tools/ if you want to go the no-build tools route.

You'll have to use alternative versions of React as well as alternative syntax to JSX.

Comment: I'm using the babel standalone to be able to use JSX in the browser. My code above is working barring the `import Greeting` stuff. I want to know about code organization in this case with my own components.

Comment: @pianoman102 I get that you are, though I cannot recommend that. React does not work in the browser like that do to being CJS. `require()` is never going to be defined. It's invalid in the browser. That's for Node only.

Comment: So are you saying I shouldn't use React like that at all? Or do you have an alternative to `require()`? Again, I'm wondering if there is an organizational paradigm I can employ to make my code more controlled.

Comment: I'm saying you cannot use React like that. React is only published as CJS. You cannot use CJS in a browser without bundling. There are alternatives, like `react-es`, but these are third-party libraries used to get around this issue with React. There is no "alternative to `require()`". React ships with `require()` in the bundle. This is not valid in a browser. This isn't an organizational issue, this is an issue that you cannot run what you have in a browser. It's a pretty famous shortcoming of React.

Comment: Well I'm running what I have in a browser, except of course the require part. If I put another script in the `<head>` section, it works great. But I wanted to avoid doing this for every single file I create, which it looks like I won't be able to avoid it, at least with what you're saying.

Comment: I think you're really confused. React's bundle has `require()` in it. You cannot run React "except ... the require part". It will error out immediately. I don't know what your vendored React is, but it's not actually React. What script are you adding to `<head>` that supposedly allows everything to "work great"? You're leaving out a lot of information here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

NOTE: Only when you proper setup of webpack and babel. require is required of cjs modules.

if you have done your setup try following.

```
1. const module = require('modulename') only when module is exports as modules.export = modulename
2. Try adding this plugin babel-plugin-import in your babel config
```

Comment: This is not applicable. I'm using CDN scripts of react and do not have a package to configure. Therefore no babel config.

Comment: you have added <script src="babel.js" /> please do check your question again.

Comment: Yes, that is because you have to use the babel-standalone to be able to use JSX. I'm not using node, or anything except straight html and javascript files. So if you're familiar with organizing lots of javascript files without having to make a new script tag for each one, that's what i'm wondering.

Comment: exactly if you are using babel than why not add plugin to it ?

Comment: How do you recommend I add a plugin to babel with the setup I currently have?